# I what to get the string between two string and replace it by blank in docx?

Tags: php

I want to get the string between two string and replace it by blank in docx? I am using this code:

```
$section ="code";
preg_match('/@@'.$section.'(.*?)'.$section.'@@/',$this->_documentXML, $display);
$this->_documentXML = str_replace($display[0], "", $this->_documentXML);
```

It works fine on Windows but not on Linux, can any one suggest something ?

Comment: `not working in linux` -- just like that? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where is `_documentXML` coming from? Is it available, and loading properly, on your Linux box?